# Convert this simple C# MySQL code to Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need some help converting this simple C# MySQL code to Java.  This is my first time learning database and I'm having a hard time with the procedural statement and executing it properly.  Thank you so much!!  Anyhow, here's the code:

```
MySqlCommand cmd;
MySqlDataReader dr = null;
int count= 0;
strStr1 = "";

cmd = new MySqlCommand("getRules", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?_Part", "1000");

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
  strStr1 += Convert.ToString(dr["value"]);
  strStr1 += ";";
  strStr1 += Convert.ToString(dr["limit"]);
  strStr1 += ";";
  count++;
}
dr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact conversion, but it should be enough to get you started:

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con, String dbName)
throws SQLException {

Statement stmt = null;
String query = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, " +
               "SALES, TOTAL " +
               "from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";
try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
        int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
        float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
        int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
        int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
        System.out.println(coffeeName + "\t" + supplierID +
                           "\t" + price + "\t" + sales +
                           "\t" + total);
    }
} catch (SQLException e ) {
    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
} finally {
    if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
}
}
```

Source: blatantly copied from the [JDBC trail on the Oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)

There's a whole list of things you can do with JDBC, including the stored procedure you use in your question. Just follow the trail and you'll get it fast.

Comment: This isn't helping me much.  I'm a newbie to this.  My problem is setting the parameters.  I'm not sure how the parameters are being set in Java but the code works in C# properly.  So can somebody just walk me through how to set the parameters in Java with the same code above, and then how to iterate it with the while loop.  That's all I need to know.  Thanks!!

Comment: That would be the [stored procedure page on the same site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#parameter_modes)